# How to hide standard List Price field based on User Profile

Tags: customer-community, configuration, order, visibility

I want to hide the standard List Price (UnitPrice) field from the Add Product screen (on standard Order object) for our Customer Community Users only.

**Use Case** - We have customer community plus licenses in our org. and we want to give access to our customers and allow them to create Orders themselves, which would be reviewed by their account managers before being processed.

We are using the standard Order and Order Line items objects for this functionality. It works fine but we do not want to show our List Price to the customer as it depends on various factors which are added later on.

Currently community users can see the List Price column on the Product selection screen, after clicking the Add Product button. We DO want the List Price column to be visible to internal users.

If I modify the available columns on the Product selection screen, it applies to all users and will hide the list price from our internal users as well -

[image]

I cannot set field level visibility for the standard ListPrice field on Pricebook entry as it is not editable.

Is there another way to hide the List Price field based on the user profile ?

Answer (score 0):

Go to the `ListPrice` field on the `Order Product` Sobject -> Click on `Set Field Level-Security` -> Unselect Visibility Checkbox for the related profiles -> Click `Save`

Comment: did you meant the Order Product Object ? because there is no ListPrice field on the Product object. Also, I've unchecked the visible checkbox on the list price field on Order Product and it doesn't work. Community User is still able to see the List Price column.

Comment: yes, where ever your ListPrice is stored

Comment: nope, doesn't work. ListPrice visibility is not editable on the Pricebook Entry object and on Order Product object it doesn't affect the visibility on the Product selection screen (as it shouldn't)

Comment: Then you have 2 options : 1) Create a new VF page for the PriceBook object and set it as the default  one, 2) Disable all visibility of all price book records from the user's profile